# How to give nice static_assert message to users when the template return type prevents it from instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, static-assert

Let's assume that I want to write function that returns pointer the first element of nonempty container.

```
// REQUIRES: c not empty
template<typename C>
auto pointer_to_first(C& c) -> decltype( &(*c.begin()) ){
    return nullptr; // TODO: implement
}
```

If I try to use this with `vector<bool>`

```
vector<bool> vb{false, false, true};
pointer_to_first(vb);
```

Compiler gives error message confusing to beginners:

> error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]  auto
>   pointer_to_first(C& c) -> decltype(&(*c.begin())){

It is confusing since beginners do not know about proxy that `vector<bool>` uses and `vb` is not a temporary.

So I wish to add `static_assert`s that the container can not be `vector<bool>`, also that container must have `begin()`, `end()`...
I know how to do that but the problem is that since overload resolution fails users will only see the compiler error message.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until we have concept, you may add an extra layer to allow to have `static_assert` and avoid SFINAE:

```
// Your SFINAE function:
template<typename C>
auto pointer_to_first_impl(C& c) ->   decltype(&(*c.begin())){
  return nullptr;// TODO: implement
}

template<typename C>
decltype(auto) pointer_to_first(C& c)
{
    // You need to implement the traits for the check
    static_assert(my_cond<C>::value, "type is incorrect");
    return pointer_to_first_impl(c);
}
```